# best way to implement 450 switch cases keeping performance in mind

Tags: vb.net, switch-statement

I have some hard-coded values for Switch case (and one case have 4 to 5 elements to be added in a list object) and the case statement is 450 + times.

I don't want to implement this by using switch case(actually increasing the length of code ) .
Here is sample code :

```
Case Set = "A"
   obj.Add("1")
   obj.Add("2")
   obj.Add("3")
   obj.Add("4")
   obj.Add("5")
Case Set = "B"
   obj.Add("66")
   obj.Add("77") 
Case Set = "C"
   obj.Add("888")
   obj.Add("999")
   obj.Add("111")
```

*Every case statement is different and the elements inside the case is different*

My product in Windows product and using vb.net .

Any other alternate way to achieve this .

Suggestions are most welcome!!!!!

Comment: It's very hard to answer without knowing what each case do. Can we see an example? Maybe they set a variable, maybe they call a method, maybe it's both, maybe it's none of those.

Comment: @the_lotus : please look at the post , I have updated it with the sample code.This are just 3 cases , there are 450 cases and each have different element to add in List obj.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Dictionary(of String, List(of String)). The Key of the dictionary is "A", "B", "C" and the List contains the element you want to add.

```
Dim dic As New Dictionary(of String, List(of String))
dic.add("A", new List(of String)({"1", "2"}))
dic.add("B", new List(of String)({"66", "77"}))
```

later you can just do this:

```
Dim key As String = "A"
obj.addRange(dic(key))
```

If you want to remove the static dictionary creation, you can easily build up  the dictionary based on a file or database.